# Using strings with StartInfo.FileName in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am getting some odd results when trying to run a process from a string:

```
                    Process p = new Process();
                    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "dump";
                    p.StartInfo.FileName = s;
                    p.Start();
```

s = run.exe "mp4:production/CATCHUP/"

I am getting odd results such as:

```
"test.exe \"mp4:production/CATCHUP/\""
```

Obviously when this command executes, it throws an exception, how can I get rid of all of the backspaces?

Comment: if you mean \" this is just rapresentation of ", so it reflects what string is actually. It's correct and should not harm process running.

Comment: Clearly the problem is that "run.exe" somehow got transformed into "test.exe".  Very strange.  Don't pay attention to the \" in the debugger output, that isn't really there.  Just its way to show an embedded double-quote, just like you'd write it in C#.  Use the text visualizer, click the magnifying glass.  Letting us guess at the exception is pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I understand your problem. At least looking on your code, it seems to me that you pass like a `p.StartInfo.FileName=s`, where `s="test.exe **\"mp4:production/CATCHUP/\"**"`
where part in bold is an argument for executable, which is wrong

Try to do something like this:

```
  Process p = new Process();
  p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "dump";
  p.StartInfo.FileName = "test.exe"; // only executable name run or test???
  p.StartInfo.Arguments = "mp4:production/CATCHUP/"; //only arguments
  p.Start();
```

Regards.

**EDIT**

Good notice that in code presented run.exe became accidentially test.exe +1 for @Hans